# Customize ObservableTransformer with RxJav/RxKotlin2 when using with compose()

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I try to write a transformation function which is used with `compose()` in order to reduce boilerplate code. It's pretty simple like this:

```
    fun <R> withSchedulers(): ObservableTransformer<R, R> {
        return ObservableTransformer {
            it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        }
    }
```

So everytime I want to subscribe to anything on `ioThread` and listen the result on `mainThread`, it's just few lines of code:

```
    Observable.just(1)
        .compose(MyUtilClass.withSchedulers())
        .subscribe()
```

But there isn't `Observable` only, but we also have `Single`, `Completable`, `Maybe` and `Flowable`. So every time I want to combine them with my `withSchedulers()` function, I have to transform it into the new type (which I don't expect).

For example,

```
Completable.fromAction { 
        Log.d("nhp", "hello world")
    }//.compose(MyUtilClass.withSchedulers()) <-- This is not compiled
            .toObservable() <--- I have to transform it into Observable
            .compose(MyUtilClass.withSchedulers())
            .subscribe()
```

So my question is, is there any way to write the above function to use with `compose()` for any kind of `Observable` (`Single`, `Completable`,...) ? Or we have to write different functions which use `ObservableTransformer`, `SingleTransformer`, ....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a helper method using `reified` type :

```
inline fun <reified T> withSchedulers(): T {
    when (T::class) {
        ObservableTransformer::class  -> return ObservableTransformer<Unit, Unit> {
            it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        } as T
        SingleTransformer::class      -> return SingleTransformer<Unit, Unit> {
            it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        } as T
        CompletableTransformer::class -> return CompletableTransformer {
            it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        } as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("not a valid Transformer type")
}
```

Examples :

```
    Observable.just("1", "2")
            .compose(withSchedulers<ObservableTransformer<String, String>>())
            .subscribe(System.out::println)

    Single.just(3)
            .compose(withSchedulers<SingleTransformer<Int, Int>>())
            .subscribe(Consumer { println(it) })

    Completable.defer { Completable.complete()  }
            .compose(withSchedulers<CompletableTransformer>())
            .subscribe { println("completed") }
```

Output :

```
1
2
3
completed
```

Probably other ways of doing this, but this came to mind.

Comment: I think about this too. RxJava2 doesn't provide an inheritance design but composition. So I think this is the only way to achieve that. Thank you. Mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: why not make use of Kotlin extension functions for that?

Comment: You could nothing wrong with that, but the original question specially included `compose()` and Transformer, extension functions would not use a Transformer, it'll only be syntactic sugar around the observable / flowable.